# Access column index by value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataset like this:
[image]

I would like a simple function/code line that makes the following:

- example: if input is 52 returns 0 --> it is in the column 0
- example: if input is 38 returns 1 --> it is in the column 1
- example: if input is 28 returns 9 --> it is in the column 9

In the dataset there are no repeated values.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Better than a dataset, you can make do with a dictionary, since you're mapping unique keys to values (the column number).

```
>>> choice_dict = {
    52: 0,
    38: 1,
    12: 2,
    82: 3,
    33: 4,
    75: 5,
    64: 6,
    76: 7,
    10: 8,
    28: 9}
>>> choice_dict[52]
0
```

You can generate this dict directly from your dataset

Comment: But I want the output to be 0, not choice_0.

Comment: same idea, just change the values. (Updated)

Answer (score 1):

The following will return the index of the element:

```
df.loc[0].tolist().index(...)
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming it's a single row, you can just turn all of the values of that row into a list and return the index of the value in the list, using that to select the column name from a list of column names as such:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[1],'b':[2],'c':[3]})
df.columns[df.iloc[0].values.tolist().index(3)]
```

output

```
'c'
```